# Python Selenium - How can I accept popup alert in headless mode?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
try:
    
    case = Select(driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'status'))
    case.select_by_value('1')
    
    # POP UP CONFIRMATION
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present())
    time.sleep(1)   
    #  driver.execute_script("window.alert = function() {};")
    driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
    # driver.implicitly_wait(60)
    time.sleep(10)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'link1')))

except: 

    UnexpectedAlertPresentException
```

Code returned this error `selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException` when I was in headless mode, even with the `except: UnexpectedAlertPresentException` line of code.

Saw another post which suggested adding

```
driver.execute_script("window.alert = function() {};")
```

to my code but it just looped through the entire `try` code chunk and did nothing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.